# php include not working on my html

Tags: php, linux, apache, centos

Now I'm migrating my site to new server where the site was not working properly. after I debug the issue, its due to "php include not working".

so I did some testing to find the issue. for that. I just create simple html file with include tag

file name : test1.php
file content:

```
<html lang="en">
<? include 'webcss.php' ?>
</html>
```

New server:  Executing the file through cli

```
[root@localhost test]# php test1.php 
<html lang="en">
<? include 'webcss.php' ?>
</html>
[root@localhost test]#
```

Existing server : Executing the same cli command. it shows the output.

```
[root@www test]# php test1.php 
<html lang="en">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> <!-- TO SHOW ARROWS -->
<!--  FONTS  -->
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,300,900,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/font-awesome.min.css" />
<!--  //FONTS  -->

<!--  JQUERY CSS  -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/jquery/flexslider.css" />
<!--  //JQUERY CSS  -->

<!--  ANIMATE CSS  -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/animate/animate.css" />
<!--  //ANIMATE CSS  -->

<!--  SWITCH COLOR RIGHT PANEL CSS  -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/switch.color.css" />
<!--  //SWITCH COLOR RIGHT PANEL CSS  -->

<!--  CSS  -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css" />
<!--  //CSS  -->

<!--  THEMES COLOR STYLE  -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/template_bg/light.background.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/template_color/yellow.color.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/template_color/turquoise.color.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/template_color/pink.color.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/template_color/purple.color.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/template_color/green.color.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/template_color/red.color.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/template_color/blue.color.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/template_color/lightgreen.color.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/template_color/lightred.color.css" />
<!--  //THEMES COLOR STYLE  -->

</html>
[root@www test]#
```

Both servers are same hardware, Operating system and php version. I don't know what was the reason for the same code not running on new server.

Someone please help to fix this issue. so that I can move my site to new prod datacenter.

Note : I verified the php settings on both servers by using phpinfo. both are same.

I don't have any idea what parameters I need to check.

OS: CentOS 7

PHP : 5.4.16

Comment: change `<?` to `<?php` for a start

Comment: ^ Best to avoid short open tags since it is not enabled by default and is generally a bad practice.

Comment: Check opening tag as Jeff said and also check the script exists and the route to it is the correct.

Comment: are short tags enabled? http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Answer (score 2):

Try `<?php include 'webcss.php' ?>` not `<? include 'webcss.php' ?>` because, as said in the php doc, it's discouraged

Comment: `<?` is short tags syntax, it's perfectly valid http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php - they just might not have them enabled on their system.

Comment: i know, but as said in the doc, 'which is discouraged'

Comment: Well your *"its <?php include 'webcss.php' ?> not <? include 'webcss.php' ?>"* statement interprets to telling them that it's "wrong", which it isn't. It's probably just not enabled.

Comment: yep, maybe not the right syntax in my sentence, i change that ;)